# Read Xlsx File and Produce Json With Node

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, excel

I am using the [XLSX](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) npm module to read the File, and Creating the Json But the Date Is Not Coming Properly here my xlsx file.

[image]

I am using this code to Read the file

```
XLSX = require('xlsx'),
exports.read = function (req, res) {
var workBook = XLSX.readFile('sample.xlsx');
    var sheet_name_list = workBook.SheetNames;
    var headers = {};
    var data = [];

        var workSheet = workBook.Sheets['sample'];
        return res.json(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workSheet));
        for (var i in workSheet) {
            if (i[0] === '!') continue;
            //parse  the column, row, and value
            var col = i.replace(/[0-9]/g, '')
            var row = parseInt(i.replace(/[A-Z]/g, ''));
            var value = workSheet[i].v;
            //store header names
            if (row == 1) {
                headers[col] = value;
                continue;
            }
            if (!data[row]) {
                data[row] = {};
            }

            data[row][headers[col]] = value;
        }
        //droping the first two rows of empty
        data.shift();
        data.shift();
        console.log(data);
        res.json(data)


    });
```

the Json is Coming Like this

```
[{'Report Date':45678
    'Name':'AAA',
    'office':'xxxx'
    },
    {'Report Date':45876
    'Name':'ccc',
    'office':'ggg'
    }]
```

I want the output Json like this

```
 [{'Report Date':'19-05-2016'
    'Name':'AAA',
    'office':'xxxx'
    },
    {'Report Date':'20-05-2016'
    'Name':'ccc',
    'office':'ggg'
    }]
```

Comment: can anybody please help me on this

Answer (score 1):

There according hints from this [issue](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/issues/59) code bellow works for me:

```
XLSX = require('xlsx');
var conv = require('ssf');
var workBook = XLSX.readFile('sample.xlsx');

var workSheet = workBook.Sheets['sample'];
var test = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workSheet);
//test = [{'Report Date':45678, 'Name':'AAA', 'office':'xxxx'},{'Report Date':45876, 'Name':'ccc', 'office':'ggg'}]
for(var i=0;i<test.length;i++) {
    for(var key in test[i]) {
        if(key.length - key.indexOf('Date') == 4) {
            test[i][key] = conv.format('dd-mm-yyy', test[i][key]);
        }
    }
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(test).replace(/,/g,',\n'));
```